# All but last line in multi-line data not appearing in SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Having looked high and low, I must ask ... how does this output in SQL Developer:

```
BUBBA GUY
P.O. BOX 123
YULEE, FL   32257
```

become this in SQL*Plus:

```
YULEE, FL   32257OX 123
```

Query:

```
SELECT  FIRSTNAME || ' ' || LASTNAME || CHR(13) || 
        ADDRESS || CHR(13) || 
        CITY || ', ' || STATE || '   ' || ZIP || CHR(13) AS " "
FROM    CITIZENS;
```

I understand lines/columns/data can get truncated ... but I am perplexed as to how the order of the elements in the line get mangled?

Comment: Your title says "SQL*Plus", yet in the question you ask about "SQL Developer". What are you using?

Comment: @a_horse, he's comparing the output between SQL Developer and SQL*Plus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `CHR(13)` to `CHR(10)`.

`CHR(13)` is the carriage return character, which causes the cursor to move back to the left edge of the screen; thus, the data from the next line overwrites the preceding line.  `CHR(10)` is the linefeed character, which *should* (famous last words :-) cause the cursor to move to the next line and left edge, but that's system dependent.  If changing `CHR(13)` to `CHR(10)` doesn't fix it, try changing `CHR(13)` to `CHR(10) || CHR(13)`.

Share and enjoy.